# How to open new dialog when authenticate with Facebook using Socialite Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-socialite

I want make Social login with Socialite Laravel, but when user authenticate with Social account, I want open new dialog windows ( like this )

https://media.giphy.com/media/WS0ZQ4DPME3JJW21ay/giphy.gif

How do I make it ? 
Thank you!

Comment: You will need to write some javascript

Comment: Hello Jerodev, could you show me an example to resolve this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

The following allows you to open a popup for user to sign in using **Facebook**:

```
return Socialite::driver('facebook')->asPopup()->redirect();
```

Comment: Hi jagjit singh, when I use your hint, I get an error message : "You are using a display type of 'popup' in a large browser window or tab. For a better user experience, show this dialog with our JavaScript SDK without specifying an explicit display type. The SDK will choose the best display type for each environment. Alternatively, set height and width on your window.open() call to properly size this dialog if you have special requirements precluding you from using the SDK. This message is only visible to developers of your application." <br /> How to resolve this problem ?